# Comparing linear models

Tags: linear-model, model-comparison

My Linear Models professor said that it is possible sometimes to obtain two different linear models for the same data, such that the models cannot be compared to determine which is better. How can this be?

As an example he mentioned  models that have different scales. What does it mean for models to have different scales, and why does it make them incomparable?

Is scale mismatch the only reason for models to be incomparable?

Is it only possible to compare a nested model to the full model that it derives from? If not, how does one compare two models that are not hierarchically related?

Comment: Why not ask your professor exactly what he meant? I'd guess he was saying there are no formal tests for comparing two models when the response (dependent variable) is expressed differently in each; e.g. $\log Y$ in one, $Y$ in the other. You certainly *can* compare non-nested models with the same response, e.g. with a likelihood ratio test (though the distribution of the likelihood ratio under the null hypothesis is not always easy to get.)

Comment: I think you also might be misinterpreting what your professor meant by "better," since you can always compare different models, linear or otherwise, based on their prediction accuracy to held out (or bootstrap sampled) data. You should definitely ask your professor for clarification.

Comment: @Scortchi: Thanks. 1. Why can't you compare two models if the response is expressed differently in each? 2. What would the null hypothesis be for a likelihood ratio test if the response is the same?

Comment: (1) Their likelihoods are in different units - as @David points out, you can compare their predictive accuracy (though you still have to decide on what scale you measure this). (2) Model #1 or Model #2 - whichever you choose as the null.

Comment: When trying to understand what someone meant when they said something, the person to ask is the person who said it.

Comment: @Scortchi: What about comparing the $R^2$s? Can we do this when the response is expressed differently?

Comment: If you think of the coefficient of determination as "proportion of variance explained" it's clear that it's affected by your choice of scale for variance.